# GIt merge doesn't remove files deleted by them

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm merging a branch into my own branch.
the other branch ('them') removed a file I have edited.
when I merge, I get a conflict. `git status` shows my file has been 'deleted by them'.

when I add this deleted file and commit, the file still stays.
Why is this? I want the file to be deleted, which is why I added its deletion.
[Example screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQedN.png)

Answer (score 5):

By issuing `git add` you tell Git that you still want to keep the file.

You need to issue `git rm` in this case to tell Git that you don't want to keep the file.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm merging a branch into my own branch. the other branch ('them') removed a file I have edited. when I merge, I get a conflict.

Right.  That's why the file *isn't* deleted: you modified it, and they removed it, and Git does not know how to combine these two operations.

> `git status` shows my file has been 'deleted by them'.

Note that `git status` at this point is showing something special.  A "normal" `git status`—here I use the word *normal* to mean *one that occurs when there is no conflict involving this particular file*—would tell you about the `git diff --name-status` result of comparing HEAD-vs-index, and then index-vs-working-tree, for that file.  But because there are conflicts for that file, `git status` prints something else entirely.

The "deleted by them" status is a result of the following index information about the file (which I will call "file *F* " here):

- There is a stage-1 entry, meaning the file existed in the merge base.
- There is a stage-2 entry, differing from the stage-1 entry: this is your modified copy.
- There is no stage-3 entry, indicating that the file was removed in their commit.

> when I add this deleted file and commit, the file still stays. Why is this?

The `git add` command initially ignores the non-zero-stage copies of *F*.  Instead, it looks to your working tree:

- If there is a copy of *F* in your working tree, it copies that copy of *F* into Git as a stage-zero ("normal", i.e., unconflicted) entry, erasing the nonzero staged copies.
- If there is *no* copy of *F* in your working tree, it erases all index entries (in this case for stages 1 and 2).

The conflict message, when it was emitted, reminded you that Git was leaving your modified file in your working tree—the same copy that appears in stage 2 in Git's index.  Since you did not remove this copy, `git add` puts this one into stage-zero.

You can either remove file *F*, then use `git add` as before, or just use `git rm F`.  When using `git rm` you sometimes get a complaint from Git, but the file does get removed.

Answer (score 0):

first you delete 'foo' in new branch and when you merge it to master it should not show the foo file
but after that you switch to master branch and make a new foo again and put new information in it
so that makes conflicts
first make a foo file in master then delete it in newbranch and then merge